# VPN adapter settings keep reverting on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, vpn, sstp

A few times a day, my VPN connection will disconnect. When I attempt to reconnect I get an error that says my username and password is not recognized.

[image: VPN Error Message]

To resolve this, I need to go into the settings for my VPN adapter, and uncheck the box that says "Automatically use my Windows logon name and password". I also change the VPN type from `Automatic` to `SSTP`.

[image]

After making these changes, I am able to connect to the VPN again. (I have to reeneter my credentials). A few hours later, my VPN will disconnect, and I have to repeat this process all over again.

What is making Windows revert these settings? Is there anything I can do to fix this.

My IT department insists this is a problem with my PC, and not a problem with the VPN service.

I am using Windows 10 Pro 20H2. I am not connected to a domain.

Comment: When the VPN disconnects, have the changes you made reverted back to the values seen in your image, even if you already changed them once?

Comment: Yes, my image shows the reverted values. To fix it, I need to **uncheck** the "Use my Windows username" checkbox. I can leave the VPN type on Automatic, and it will still connect. I usually change it to SSTP as per my IT department's recommendation.

Comment: Which VPN client product are you using on your computer? Do you know what is the VPN server product and is it internal to your organization?

Comment: I am just using the built in VPN client in Windows. I am not sure what the server is (I am going to guess CISCO). I can try to find out for sure.

Comment: No real need for it. One question is why you're getting disconnected, is perhaps the VPN connection time set to limited by IT? You could try to [disable Windows Defender Credential Guard](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/68935-enable-disable-credential-guard-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: We use "Routing and Remote Access on Windows Server 2016", I don't know why I thought it was Cisco.

We have many users connecting to the same VPN, but I seem to be the only person experiencing this problem. For that reason, I don't think it's a time limit issue.

I can look into disabling Credential Guard for a bit to see if it helps.

Comment: Do you have an incorrect entry (or multiple entries) in [Credential Manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/accessing-credential-manager-1b5c916a-6a16-889f-8581-fc16e8165ac0) for the VPN?

Comment: Good suggestion. I had a look, but I didn't see anything in Credential Manager specific to my VPN. I removed some of the entries that seemed like they could be related, but the issue still remains.

Comment: Another suggestion: Look for the VPN settings file (`.pbk` file). It might be for current user under `%AppData%\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk`, or for all users under `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk`. The file and/or sub-folders may be hidden. If you find the one corresponding to your VPN, please add its contents to your post. You could also try to set it to read-only or traffic the permissions so only you can modify it (take first a backup).

Comment: We may have a winner here. I set the PBK file to be read-only, and the problem seems to be at least partially fixed. I was still disconnected from the VPN, but now, I was able to reconnect without having to modify my adapter settings. If you want, feel free to write your suggestion as an answer, so that I can mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some software is likely trafficking with the settings of the VPN,
enabling the option of "Automatically use my Windows logon name and password",
so that after a disconnection the VPN reconnects using the
wrong credentials.

The VPN settings file is a `.pbk` file found at:

- Current user: `%AppData%\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk`
- All users: `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk`

The file and/or sub-folders may be hidden, so Explorer may need to be set to
show hidden files in order to locate the file.

Once the `.pbk` file is found, you could try to set it to read-only or traffic
its permissions so only you can modify it
(taking a backup copy is recommended).

If you wish to track down the program that does the change
(knowing that the answer might simply be "Windows"),
you may try the following resources:

- [Detect what process is changing a file on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/521476/detect-what-process-is-changing-a-file-on-windows)
- [How can I find out which process and user is modifying a file?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130827-00/?p=3393)

Comment: Thanks for all of the time you put into helping me fix this. I really appreciate it.